# Why (reverese) - reversed list variable prints a 'None' in Python

Tags: python

```
mylist = ['banana', 'apple', 'papaya', 'cherry']
revered_list = mylist.reverse()
print(mylist)
print(revered_list)

#Output:
# ['cherry', 'papaya', 'apple', 'banana']
# None
```

Why is the 'None' given when the variable is printed? What really is happening behind the scene.

Comment: `.reverse()` reverses in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: In addition, if you dont need to keep a copy a your reversed list, you can do `print(reversed(mylist))`, which is a iterator that iterates the list in reversed order

Comment: I don't get the order of execution, shouldn't the printed variable must give the reversed list?

Comment: In the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) about mutable sequence types, you can read that `.reverse()` modifies the sequence in place and does not return the reversed sequence.

Comment: @RajithaAmarasinghe - you could try to run your code here - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @Daniel Hao - WOW, that was so helpful, I didn't know about that site. I was using Thonny for the same purpose, but this layout is more comprehensive and clean I guess. Yes, I got the answer to my question. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Daniel Hao - agree with you 100%

Answer (score 2):

Because `reverse()` method does not return anything ( which means it return `None`, that explains why you get `None`) and reverse the list in place, so in your example, you can get reveresed list like this:

```py
mylist = ['banana', 'apple', 'papaya', 'cherry']
mylist.reverse()
print(mylist) # you get a modified list (reversed)
```

if you want to make a copy of reversed list, then use `reversed()` function:

```py
mylist = ['banana', 'apple', 'papaya', 'cherry']
reversed_list = reversed(mylist)
print(reversed_list)
```

Comment: OK, now I got it, it is the difference between 'reverse' and 'reversed', your answer was loud and clear. Thank you so much for reaching out :-)